# Python dataframe get borders of zeros segments throught the column

Tags: python, pandas, series, data-munging

I have a pandas series:

```
s = [3,7,8,0,0,0,6,12,0,0,0,0,0,8,5,0,2]
```

I want to find all the indices in which there is a start or an end of a zeros segment, where the number of zeros is more than 3
so here I want to get:

```
[8,12]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way using [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) considering `s` is the series (not list as you have provided):

*First group the list in consecutive elements for the index that meets the condition:*

```
import more_itertools as mit
a = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(s.loc[s.eq(0)].index.tolist())]
```

*Second , select the first and last entries form the list*

```
list(set([i[0] for i in a]+[x[-1] for x in a]))
#[3, 5, 8, 12, 15]
```

**EDIT** for getting first and last index where 0 is more than 3 use:

```
list(set([i[0] for i in a if len(i)>3]+[x[-1] for x in a if len(x)>3]))
#[8, 12]
```

Comment: thank you , and if I want the segment of zeros will be with more than 3 zeros?

Comment: @okuoub didnt get that. you wanted the first and last index of consecutive zeroes right? the code does the same?

Comment: yes but I want to filter out segments with less than 3 zeros (please see the edit)

Comment: @okuoub check EDIT acc to the new question use same solution with `list(set([i[0] for i in a if len(i)>3]+[x[-1] for x in a if len(x)>3]))`

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [3,7,8,0,0,0,6,12,0,0,0,0,0,8,5,0,2]
idx = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == 0 and (s[i+1] != 0 or s[i-1] != 0):
        idx.append(i)
print (idx)
# result :[3, 5, 8, 12, 15]
```

Comment: and if I want the segment of zeros will be with more than 3 zeros?

Comment: the code is customized for any length of the list and the number of segments of zeros

Answer (score 0):

Define a flag that tells the loop whether to check the existence or absence of 0.
`entryFlag` tells whether to check the entry of 0s or the exit.

```
s = [3,7,8,0,0,0,6,12,0,0,0,0,0,8,5,0,2]
entryFlag=True
i=0
s2=[]
for x in s:

    if entryFlag:
        if x==0:
            s2.append(i)
            entryFlag=False
    else:
        if x!=0:
            s2.append(i-1)
            entryFlag=True
    i+=1
print(s2)
```